# grails 3.1.8 stuck saying resolving dependencies

Tags: grails

I am on Windows 8 and using NetBeans 8.1 for grails. Grails project is successfully created but when i add Domain class or controller or something similar it stuck their saying resolving dependencies......

But when I run NetBeans with admin previllage it gives following error while creating Domain Class

```
 Error initializing classpath: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\n\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13-bin\4xsgxlfjcxvrea7akf941nvc7\gradle-2.13-bin.zip (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

How can I solve this issue...... I had also tried grails cli problem is same

Comment: You should probably reboot.  Could be some rogue process holding up exclusive access to that file.

Comment: its not working same problem;

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, but after I use intellij open the project and imported as gradle type, it suddenly works, I 'm looking into this issue, you can have a try first.